# Отличие события в c# от ссылки на метод

Tags: c#

Я недавно начал программировать на c#  и не очень понял зачем  нужны события, если эти события всёравно гдето генерируются методом. Понимаю, что тут что-то не так, но на мой взгляд, не легче ли просто создать метод. и при выполнении каких-то действий прописать этот метод, чем создавать событие с данным методом, а потом пытаться его запустить и отлавливать? (Про делегаты я вообще чёто не въехал пока,как они работают)

Вообщем может не очень выразился, просто хочу понять, зачем создавать события а потом гдето его генерировать методом, ведь можно в этом месте напрямик сослаться на этот метод.

Comment: покажите код, который по вашему удобнее использования нативных событий, и я вам докажу обратное

Comment: @Spectre

- Я тут набросал небольшой прототип `difference viewer'a` *(первое, что в голову пришло :)*. В общем-то, я знаю пару вариантов, как похожее можно было бы реализовать без использования `event'ов`, однако вроде вариант с эвентами кажется наиболее разумным. Сможете доказать обратное?

- [**http://pastebin.com/Pid6hdcZ**][1]

[1]: http://pastebin.com/Pid6hdcZ

Comment: @Spectre Тьфу. Я почему-то неправильно прочитал ваш коммент и подумал, что вы умеете любой код с эвентами переписывать без них. Ладно, зря старался :)

Comment: =)

по-моему, единственный способ избавиться от ивентов - написать собственный аналог Public/Subscriber'a, но фактически будет тоже самое

Comment: @Spectre Да, еще и получится в 100 раз хуже :) Блин, обидно, я уже предвкушал интересную дискуссию.

Answer (score 4):

Прочитай про события и делегаты, а пока смотри как я использовал их у себя.

Допустим есть 3 светофора и презентер( получает информацию от них и преобразовывает в нужную для определенных целей).
При вызове события(допустим, событие смены состояния лампочек) в одном из светофоров

```
UpdateState(TempLamps, this.Type); //вызов события
```

должен срабатывать метод презентера , который будет принимать некоторые аргументы от светофора. Поэтому я записываю в делегат события этот метод

```
A.UpdateState += new WinFormsTrafficLights.UpdateEvent(TLStateChanged); // при срабатывании события светофора А будет запускаться метод TLStateChanged
```

Теперь при каждом вызове события будет срабатывать нужный нам метод. Записать методов в наше события можно сколько нам нужно (в пределах разумного).
Согласитесь, намного удобней чем использовать метод вместо события и указать в нем какие методы вызывать в дальнейшем времени.

Также если у нас есть таймер, очень удобно записывать в делегат события метод, который будет вызываться при каждом тике таймера

```
BlinkingTimer.Elapsed += Blink;
```

Извините если что не так написал, опыта пока маловато.